# component still visible after delete unless i refresh

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

iam using mern stack and i am performing crud operations but upon delete the data is still visible unless i refresh the page. I am using context to manage state and it is working fine for adding data but for deleting data i have to refresh how can this be solved?
note: i logged the data in the console on delete and it is logging the data without the deleted one

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import WorkoutDetails from "../components/WorkoutDetails";
import WorkoutForm from "../components/WorkoutForm";
import useWorkoutContext from "../hooks/useWorkoutContext";

const Home = () => {
const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutContext();
useEffect(() => {
const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/workouts", {
method: "GET",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
console.log(response);
const json = await response.json();
console.log(json);
if (response.ok) {
dispatch({ type: "SET_WORKOUTS", payload: json });
      }
    };
fetchWorkouts();
[]);
 return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="workouts">
        {workouts &&
workouts.map((workout) => (
            <WorkoutDetails Workout={workout} key={workout._id} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <WorkoutForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;




import {useEffect} from "react";
import useWorkoutContext from "../hooks/useWorkoutContext";

const WorkoutDetails = ({ Workout }) => {
useEffect(() => {
console.log("Component is rendering");
   });
const { dispatch } = useWorkoutContext();
const handleDelete = async () => {
const response = await fetch(>       `http://localhost:3001/api/workouts/${Workout._id}`,
      {
method: "DELETE",
      }
    );
const json = await response.json();
if (response.ok) {
dispatch({ type: "DELETE_WORKOUT", payload: json });>    
}
console.log(json);
  };
return (
    <div className="workout-details">
     <h4>{Workout.title}</h4>
      <p>
        <strong>Load (kg):</strong> {Workout.load}
     </p>
     <p>
        <strong>Reps:</strong> {Workout.reps}
     </p>
      <p>{Workout.createdAt}</p>
      <span onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WorkoutDetails;
```